# How to view graddle defined available dependency version?

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Background:

I'm new to graddle, I have used maven.

Now I am working on build IDEA plugin with graddle, but I do not know how to view the available dependency version in graddle.

In maven, we have maven repository to search and view different dependency version, like this:

[image]

Now in graddle, I have this:

```
intellij {
    version '2022.3.1'
    plugins 'java'
}
```

I just guss and fill the version number 2022.3.1 and it works, but some other version number not work, and I do not know the difference among different version.

Is there some place I can view all availabe intellij version and its description?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between gradle repository and a maven repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49608449/what-is-the-difference-between-gradle-repository-and-a-maven-repository)

Comment: @aSemy Thanks, it helps part of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be found in the documentation for the IntelliJ plugin:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tools-gradle-intellij-plugin.html#configuration-intellij-extension

> All available JetBrains IDEs versions can be found at [IntelliJ Artifacts](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/intellij-artifacts.html) page.